# The number of inversions in a permutation is equal to the number of its inverse permutation.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

I need to prove that the sign of a permutation is equal to the sign of the inverse of the permutation. I understand it is true, but how do you proof that the #inversions of $\sigma$= #inversions of $\sigma^{-1}$? Can anyone help me out? I know that the inversions are not the same, I tried it with an example.

Comment: It is much easier to prove this via the product formula of the sign

Comment: yes the $\-1^{#inversions of \sigma$} right?

Comment: what is the product, $\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma^{-1})$?

Comment: sgn(identity) .

Answer (score 6):

Saying $\sigma$ inverts $i$ and $j$ means that $i$ and $j$ come in the opposite order to $\sigma(i)$ and $\sigma(j)$.

Therefore $\sigma$ inverts $i$ and $j$ if and only if $\sigma^{-1}$ inverts $\sigma(i)$ and $\sigma(j)$. This gives a one-to-one correspondence between the inversions of $\sigma$ and $\sigma^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$sgn(\sigma)\cdot sgn(\tau)=sgn(\sigma \tau)$$

Comment: So, you just say that sigma(j)^-1  - sigma(i)^-1 = sigma(j) -sigma(i). And why is that?

Comment: It is much harder to see in the first formula , the second hint is a lot better (and the first leads to the second hint anyway). I will edit the first hint out.